# Normal probability plot

Tags: regression, assumptions, qq-plot

[image][image]

**I need opinion about this plot 
Do you consider normality here violated 
Thanks**

and here is the histogram of the residuals

Comment: If you would, please add a histogram of the modeling error, in this case (predicted - SLDWASTE).

Comment: @Ahamd What you have here *isn't* a normal probability plot and this wouldn't be a suitable display by which to judge, but normality is almost always not actually the case anyway (it's a model for something, not a fact about it)

Comment: Visually, the histogram give me the impression that it is asymmetric.

Answer (score 1):

What you have shown us is **not** a normal probability plot (also called qq-plot). But the histogram of residuals do not show anything anomalous, but a qq-plot would be more informative. The other plot (predicted versus observed) neither shows anything indicating departure from linearity.